# How to use "IS" and "=" in MySQL in the right way

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to figure out when to use "is", "=" since it seems like these two don't work the same way in SQL.

I've tried to switch these two in different commands, and I thought I'd receive the same result, but seems like SQL would only recognize one of them with particular functions

```
WHERE event_date **=** '2013-12-22'
```

And I tried to use "IS" instead of "=" for the above command

```
WHERE event_date **IS** '2013-12-22'

Then I got an error code, also in another practice question. I wanted to use "IS" before "BETWEEN", that failed too.
```

WHERE 
  affected_customers **BETWEEN** 50000 
  AND 150000

```
I tried to put
```

WHERE 
  affected_customers **IS BETWEEN** 50000 
  AND 150000

Comment: So don't use `is`.  You seem to know how to use `=` and `between`.

Comment: there's also `IN` which can also be similar to `=` and `BETWEEN`

Answer (score 2):

`IS` word cannot just be added before another operator.

`IS` operator is used for [checking value against boolean](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is)

`IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` are used for checking values against NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

SQL operators don't necessarily need to be use like how you construct an English sentence.

`IS` operator is usually use with the `NULL` operator, hence `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` - used to checked if a value is `NULL`.

`affected_customers BETWEEN 50000 AND 150000` is enough and logical, you'll get use to it as you go along with your programming life.

Best of luck to your journey!